# pip is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, command-line, python, powershell

I have installed pip and distribute, and no errors came up. But when I enter pip into the cmd or windows powershell, it gives me an error. However, when I `import pip` into python, no errors come up.

I have got the python directory in the path environment variable.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have entered this in your ***PATH*** in the System Environmental Variables.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts;
```

This path is the default given that you have Python 2.7 installed and you didn't change the installation directory of pip. Make sure there is no space before or after this or any other variable. Make sure you add a semicolon before this new PATH if it is not already there.

Comment: Thank you for the checking spaces tip. It was the problem in my case